# FIPS Compliance and BouncyCastle

Tags: android, cryptography, bouncycastle, fips

I wish to know if my Android App is FIPS 140-2 compliant if it uses only the crypto algorithms provided [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexa.pdf)? I use SpongyCastle to implement these algorithms.

Edit: A generalised question : Can open-source libraries like BouncyCastle/SpongyCastle be used in a module that can be FIPS Certified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouncy Castle is not FIPS 140-2 certified, so therefore SpongyCastle is not certified.  Mocana's [NanoCrypto](https://mocana.com/nanocrypto.html) has a FIPS 140-2 certification for a few specific android OS/hardware combinations.

Generally speaking, FIPS 140-2 certification requires quite a lot of money, so don't expect an open-source library (other than OpenSSL) to be FIPS certified

Comment: "certified" isn't necessarily the same as "compliant", though. I do believe SpongyCastle is compliant, although that may not be true forever.

Comment: That's not true.  compliance with FIPS 140-2 requires an independent certification of the software package.  BouncyCastle hasn't undergone this certification.  check out [this post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/question-of-importance-of-fips-in-security-implementations) from the security StackExchange, it explicitly calls out BouncyCastle as not FIPS 140-2 certified.

Comment: Suppose that I create a java crypto library, which inturn uses BouncyCastle, to be used in my App. Can I get this library FIPS 140-2 Certified even with the money that's required?

Comment: @MediumOne: there is no inherent reason why an open source library cannot be FIPS 140-2 certified. It is a question of complying with the FIPS 140-2 spec and paying for a successful evaluation.

Comment: From OpenSSL "New FIPS 140-2 validations (of any type) are slow (6-12 months is typical), expensive (US$50,000 is probably typical for an uncomplicated validation), and unpredictable (completion dates are not only uncertain when first beginning a validation, but remain so during the process)." Being an author of a common criteria certified product, I can tell you that 50K is pretty cheap, and is extremely unlikely to include man-hours spend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Certifications cost a non negligible amount of money especially for open source projects, however BouncyCastle has now a FIPS 140-2 certified version.

Certifications can be searched on csrc.nist.gov
https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search?SearchMode=Basic&ModuleName=Bouncy+Castle&CertificateStatus=Active&ValidationYear=0

e.g.
https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/3514

other resources
https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips_faq.html
https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BCFipsIn100.pdf